# Convert String to e-mail address

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am writing a script that will rename so exported PST files to match the format needed for import to a new system.

I am trying to use regular expression in VBScript to do this along with Replace.

An example string:

```
JoeBloggs_Export_001.pst
```

Required End Result:

```
Joe.Bloggs@emaildomain.com._001.pst
```

I have obviously got the replace of *Export* with @emaildomain.com. working with Replace.

I am struggling to get the insert of . between the First-name and Last-name, I figured using a regular expression to do this would be the best approach. I am struggling with getting this to work. Obviously the length of the first-name varies.

I have now tried various regular expressions, so rather than sharing any of these I am hoping getting a fresh set of eyes will help to highlight where I have been going wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to break the pascal cased name on caps you can capture lower-case followed by upper-case & insert a ".";

```
set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
re.global = true

filename = "JoeBloggs_Export_001.pst"

msgbox replace(re.Replace(fileName, "$1.$2"), "_Export_", "@emaildomain.com._")

>> Joe.Bloggs@emaildomain.com._001.pst
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, Works a treat! I knew it would be something simple and I was over complicating it.